# Replace value in script with value from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been asked to set a script that replaces some values with found values from certain elements inside the below script. I don't have access to a database and can only use jQuery or javascript. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="info"><span>Manufacturer</span> </div>
```

Script:

```
var ccs_cc_args = ccs_cc_args || [];

  ccs_cc_args.push(['cpn', 'CPN']); 
  ccs_cc_args.push(['mf', 'MFR_NAME']); //replace MFR_NAME dynamically with the value from the span element above
  ccs_cc_args.push(['pn', 'MPN']); 
  ccs_cc_args.push(['upcean', 'EAN_CODE']); 
  ccs_cc_args.push(['lang', 'nl']);
  ccs_cc_args.push(['market', 'NL']);

  (function () {
     var o = ccs_cc_args; o.push(['_SKey', '3a535060']); o.push(['_ZoneId', '6cddbf26bb']); 
     var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
     sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.cnetcontent.com/jsc/h.js';
     var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; n.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, n);
  })();
```

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `array.push(x); array.push(y);`, you can do: `array.push(x, y, z, etc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `span text` by using

```
$(".info span").text()
```

Try this

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['mf', $(".info span").text()]);
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't seems to update the script with the info - no errors though

Comment: Is there only one span in div ?

Comment: Have you debugged it ?

Comment: Yeah, i cant find any errors. It wont update the existing script though,.

Comment: Just check the value of `ccs_cc_args` in console to see if it is actually updated.